# What is the easiest way to push a file on the GCP AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

To verify the ownership of a domain to a mail service, I need to put a file with a specific name for verification. Is there a better way than pushing it into my app source repository?

Comment: Can you specify a little bit more, what do you mean to say by pushing a file on the GCP App Engine? Are you trying to write or read a file in App Engine?

Comment: @sotis I mean I need that the web service of my AppEngine needs to serve one specific file for only one request. In this case, the file has not even content, it's just the name, that need to be served by the AppEngine with an HTTP code 200.

Comment: You can verify the domain name by adding some records in your DNS manager provided by your domain name provider? Which mail service you are using?

Comment: @JohnSnow Indeed, I can. This is a possible solution and the way I've chosen for this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons you would have to put the file in your source and do a deployment to App Engine. If you’ve worked with a traditional web server in the past where you basically dump files into a folder and serve them this will be a bit of a change. The App Engine files are going to execute only. If you want to get in to adding other files on the fly you would need a Cloud Storage Bucket, but I don’t think that will do it for your domain verification.